# How to deploy smart contract so that average user can interact with its public functions?

Tags: contract-invocation, interfaces

I sucesfully wrote and deployed smart contract using Remix and Metask to generate hashes used as keys. This contract has few payable public functions that set or get some numbers. After deploying using Remix on mainnet, I can see "buttons"  and "text input box" in left bottom corner that can be used for interaction with contract public function.

But I need that my customer is able to interact with contract (using "buttons"  and "text input box" ).

I tried https://www.myetherwallet.com without success. After inserting ABI and bytecode, deploying contract  there was no "buttons" or "text input box" for user interaction.

After, I tried to use https://justsmartcontracts.dev. After inserting ABI and contract address, in window "Cals" or "operations"  there was no "buttons" or "text input box" for user interaction. I was onlz able to see public variables, but no public functions. Also there was problems with metamask connection.

Which software/wallet/webpage can provide "buttons" or "text input box" so that average ethererum user can interact with this smart contract?

Thank you for help [image: smart contract user interface that i need for customer]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an problem with compiler or compiller support at myetherwallet. When i used older 0.5.17 instead of 0.6., it generated longer and different abi code and everythinks works on myetherwallet.

ABI generated with compiler 0.6.6 that does not work on myetherwallet.com

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "mojeCislo",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "name": "nastavcislo",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "vypisCislo",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

ABI generated with 0.5.17 compiler that works successfully on myetherwallet.com

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": true,
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "mojeCislo",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "name": "nastavcislo",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": true,
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "vypisCislo",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

[image: Now average ethereum user can interact with my contract]